# Phantomjs uploadFile within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, file-upload, phantomjs

I am trying to upload an image, in a form within an iframe. I try to switch to the frame first and then call a uploadFile. The switch works but then the upload doesn't work. I think upload file gets evaluated on the environment of the main page so the selector fails, is there a way to specify the input within the iframe?

```
browser.page.switchToFrame("iframeName");
// console.log(browser.page.frameContent);
browser.page.evaluate(function(capt) {
    console.log("test");
    var elementIter = document.evaluate("//input[@name='photo_upload']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); // fix to go more than 1 level down
    if(item = elementIter.iterateNext())
    {
        console.log("id is "+item.id)
    }
},' ');
browser.page.uploadFile('input[id=userfile_input]', '/home/ubuntu/new_bot/profile.jpg');
```

The test thingie, is just something to see if the js gets evaluated in the correct environment and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, apparently the switchToFrame using the frame name wouldnt work when using built in methods of phantomjs. When i used switchToFrame by position it worked.

```
browser.page.switchToFrame(0);          
browser.page.uploadFile('input[name=photo_upload]', '/home/ubuntu/new_bot/profile.jpg');
```